# Passing data from main function to getServerSideProps

Tags: javascript, session, next.js

I've been having trouble with passing data from the function component to to getServerSideProps method. I just started learning nextjs and can't really seem to figure this one out. I am trying to use the context from _app but when I use it in getserversideprops it throw errors that it has to be in the main function component. Information on the internet is pretty scarce, I couldn't really find any other place where I could get some help.

[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLLSQ.png)

[This is the error I keep getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3a1W.png)

Comment: it's well described in the error message

Comment: Please add your code as a snippet to the question, do not use images for code.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you are calling a hook from outside a component.

The function `getServerSideProps` is not part of the component, it is run before the component is rendered in the server-side (SSR).

I don't know what your function `useContext` does so I can't go in more details about this example.

Anyway, in one of my next.js applications, I use cookies to store the user information and keep it from page to page after the login. I am using [passport.js](http://www.passportjs.org/) to handle it.